# Android studio Logcat slow in displaying results

Tags: android, intellij-idea, android-studio

I am currently using Version 1.0.2 of Android Studio, The logcat displays errors and other details after a significant delay, is this a known bug, I did not find any material on the internet regarding this.

If anyone has found a fix or work around please let me know.

Comment: This seems to be Samsung related, according to Reddit
https://www.reddit.com/r/androiddev/comments/2etmfu/why_does_it_take_forever_for_logcat_to_catch_up/

Comment: For the sake of clarification, "significant" in my case was around a minute.

Comment: Looks like a samsung issue, its been over a year since i asked this question. I guess this has been fixed in the later versions but did not get time to check

Answer (score 5):

Try restarting adb

```
adb kill-server
adb start-server
```

Comment: Cool. I think restarting Android Studio has the same effect.

Comment: True, but this takes a lot less time. Plus it is possible from within Android Studio. (Side note: the Logcat window in Android Studio is rewritten in the latest beta so it may be fixed already http://tools.android.com/recent/androidstudio14beta3available)